# Postgres: PostGIS extension in a separate path

Tags: postgresql, postgis

The Linux machine I use has SuSE 12.1 with Postgres 9.4 installed (as `root`).  I was able to compile and install the PostGIS 2.5 extension in a user area.  Under this installation, I see, among other things, contrib folder, some sql files and .so files etc.

I can launch Postgres using my personal user.  How can I let Postgres know to refer to this directory where all the PostGIS extension related files/objects are available?

When I try creating the extension, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql94/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

Of course, some error is expected as Postgres doesn't know about my PostGIS installation.  But the latter does not have such a file, `postgis.control`.

I am guessing the solution is to ensure Postgres can see the .so files (may be set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?) or create a `postgis.control` file with all the relevant details etc.

Any assistance including simply pointing to documentation will be appreciated.

I see a few similar questions but no one seems to address my issue of the extension - PostGIS - in a separate directory.  They assume `root` access.

Comment: Did you run  `create extension postgis;` from your psql console after installing postgis?

Comment: Yes and it complains about "/usr/share/postgresql94/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory.  It certainly doesn't know about the postgis installation in a non-root, user area.  My question is to let postgres know about postgis.

Answer (score 1):

Like every extension, PostGIS has to be installed in the PostgreSQL extension subdirectory (under `share`).

When PostGIS is configured, it looks for `pg_config` on the `PATH`, or you can explicitly specify the `--with-pgconfig` option to `configure`.

Once you have built PostGIS, `make install` will automatically put all files in the proper place.

You are not very specific how you built PostGIS, but you must have strayed from the correct path somewhere. If you share some details, we might be able to figure out what went wrong.

---

Re-reading your question I get the impression that you installed PostGIS somewhere outside the PostgreSQL software directory because you lack the necessary `root` privilege. That simply won't work, and there is no workaround.

You'd have to install PostgreSQL somewhere where you have write access.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I guess that confirms my worst fears.  My options are to either convince our admins to install the extension or for me to try install postgres myself, at least for development purposes.  I had used "make install DESTDIR=/a/b/c" when installing postgis

Comment: If it's in your company's interest, I'm sure you will find somebody who can convince the DBAs. PostGIS is a well-known, trusted PostgreSQL extension.